# How can I include a dependency file generated by a custom command in cmake for GNU make?

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I have integrated a tool that generates some code from a text file in CMake based build environment.

This tool is also able to generate the dependency file in the GNU make format (pretty much like `gcc -MD` does it for c files).

I would like to include this dependency file in makefiles generated by CMake in order to correctly rebuild when necessary.  Unfortunately, I could not find the correct way to do this.

I tried:

- [Generated Dependency Files in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169207/generated-dependency-files-in-cmake) , but there was no answer
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=add_custom_command has the `DEPFILE` option but it only works for Ninja

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: I added an answer to your first link. Go see if it works for you.

Comment: If there is an existing question that would solve yours and just doesn't have a solution, don't create a new question. Wait for a solution to the existing one, or [put a bounty on it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). Is your question really different than [the existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45169207/11107541)? If not. This should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

try to define your file as dependency of your add_custom_target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Custom_Command_TEST)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your_gen_file.txt"
                   COMMAND /bin/date > "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your_gen_file.txt"
                   COMMAND /bin/echo "RUNNING COMMAND")

add_custom_target(GenerateFile
                  /bin/echo "RUNNING TARGET"
                  DEPENDS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your_gen_file.txt")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} GenerateFile)
```

will only rebuild the `target GenerateFile`. You could put your .txt generation step as `COMMAND` in `add_custom_command`.

output of first make:

```
[ 33%] Generating your_gen_file.txt
RUNNING COMMAND
RUNNING TARGET
[ 33%] Built target GenerateFile
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Custom_Command_TEST.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Custom_Command_TEST
[100%] Built target Custom_Command_TEST
```

output second make:

```
RUNNING TARGET
[ 33%] Built target GenerateFile
[100%] Built target Custom_Command_TEST
```

In case you want to rebuild everything again, you'll want to `make clean`.

You could also check this [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862300/how-to-make-cmake-target-executed-whether-specified-file-was-changed)

Comment: In this case, I would rebuild everytime, regardless of the content of the file which indicates the dependencies